# PHP- MySQL Search Criteria

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've developed a database having multiple fields-- approx 65 fields. I wish to give a multiple search criteria to my users,i.e. by selecting various field names in the drop down menu. I'm unable to execute it by using simple IF-ELSEIF- ELSE Statements. It gives results for only the first IF statement, while ignores the rest.

Following is the html page:

```
<form name="frm" action="search_plants.php" method="get">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="155" height="24">Select Scientific Name:</td>
      <td width="275">
                        <select name="spnm" size="1">       
                        <option value="0">  All</option>    
                        <option value="Abrus precatorius">  Abrus precatorius</option>  
                        <option value="Abutilon indicum">  Abutilon indicum</option>                    
                        <option value="Abutilon theophrasti"> Abutilon theophrasti</option>                 



                        </select>
                        </td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Family Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="fmnm" size="1">   
                        <option value="0">  All</option>
                        <option value="Fabaceae">Fabaceae</option>
                        <option value="Malvaceae">Malvaceae</option>
                        <option value="Mimosaceae">Mimosaceae</option>                      

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Geographic Location:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="znm" size="1">                    
                        <option value="0">  All</option>
                        <option value="North Gujarat">North Gujarat</option>
                        <option value="South Gujarat">South Gujarat</option>
                        <option value="South East Gujarat">South East Gujarat</option>      
                        <option value="Central Gujarat">Central Gujarat</option>
                        <option value="Kachchh">Kachchh</option>
                        <option value="Saurashtra">Saurashtra</option>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Marker:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="pnm" size="1">                    
                        <option value="0">  All</option>
                        <option value="rbcL">rbcL</option>      
                        <option value="psbA-trnH">psbA-trnH</option>    
                        <option value="matK">matK</option>  
                        <option value="rpoC1">rpoC1</option>    
                        <option value="ITS2">ITS2</option>  
                        <option value="ycf5">ycf5</option>      

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Go" name="action">
                        <label>
                        <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset">
                        </label>                        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

And the form action page is as follows, depicting only a part of the entire coding. I want to give the user an option of selecting any/all fields and be able to display it by selective search from the database. Please help me out.

```
if (($species == 0) || ($family == 0) || ($zones ==0 ) || ($marker == 0))   
    {
        if(($species==0) && ($family==0) && ($zones==0))
        {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `ncbi_bold_ plants` WHERE Marker LIKE '$marker%'" ;
        }

        elseif($species==0 &&  $family==0 &&  $marker==0)
        {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `ncbi_bold_ plants` WHERE Zones LIKE '%$zones%'";
        }

        elseif($family==0 &&  $zones==0 &&  $marker==0)
        {
        $sql="select * from `ncbi_bold_ plants` where Speciesname like '$species%'";

        }

        elseif($species==0 &&  $zones==0 &&  $marker==0)
        {
            $sql="select * from `ncbi_bold_ plants` where Family like '$family%'";

        }
    /*
    elseif($species==0 && $marker==0)
    {
        $sql="select * from `ncbi_bold_ plants` where Family like '$family%' AND Zones like '%$zones%'";
        $search_sql=mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$sql}");
    }       
    elseif($family==0 && $zones==0 && $marker==0)
    {
        $sql="select * from `ncbi_bold_ plants` where Speciesname like '$species%'";
        $search_sql=mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$sql}");
    }
    elseif($species==0 && $family==0)
    {
        $sql="select * from `ncbi_bold_ plants` where Zones like '%$zones%' AND marker like '$marker%'";
        $search_sql=mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$sql}");
    }
    elseif($species==0 && $zones==0)
    {
        $sql="select * from `ncbi_bold_ plants` where Family like '$family%' AND marker like '$marker%'";
        $search_sql=mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$sql}");
    }
    elseif($species==0 && $marker==0)
    {
        $sql="select * from `ncbi_bold_ plants` where Family like '$family%' AND Zones like '%$zones%'";
        $search_sql=mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$sql}");
    }
    */          
        else
        {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `ncbi_bold_ plants` " ;
        }

    }

    else 
    {
        $sql="select * from `ncbi_bold_ plants` where Speciesname like '$species%' and Family like '$family%' and Zones like '%$zones%' and Marker like '$marker%'";


    }

    $search_sql=mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$sql}");
```

please help me for the same. I'm unable to find a flaw in the if statement.

Comment: Could you try manually feeding in some `$species`,`$family`,`$zones`, and `$marker` and printing out the resulting `$sql`? e.g. (0,1,1,1) (will give "SELECT * FROM nci_bold_ plants"), (0,0,0,1), (0,1,0,0), ...

Comment: actually i have given these values through the drop-down menu, by fetching these 0,1, etc values in the drop-down--> "option" value.

Comment: Then try printing out your `$species`, `$family`, etc before that `if` statement, with the corresponding output `$sql`, so you can verify that an error is in fact happening (errors that are not syntactical are the hardest to track).

Comment: i did try that, and its printing the  particular species name accurately. What i think is that there's some problem with the IF statement itself.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the output of these tests? So that we can also verify? (with the corresponding $sql).

Comment: @Snids, check out my answer, I guess that can help you to avoid miles of code but still efficient enough to fit your needs. Test it and let me know do you need any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Try this simple function:**

```
function create_query($p_species, $p_family, $p_zones, $p_marker) {
  $options = array(
    'Speciesname' => $p_species,
    'Family' => $p_family,
    'Zones' => $p_zones,
    'Marker' => $p_marker
    );
  $cond = '';
  $noopt = true;
  foreach ($options as $column => $value) {
    if ($value !== 0) {
      $noopt = false;
      if ($cond != '') $cond .= ' AND ';
      $cond .= "$column LIKE '%$value%'";
      }
    }
  return $noopt ? false : "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_ plants WHERE $cond;";
  }
```

This function returns **false** if all parameters are zero, otherwise it returns query string.

### **Example #1:**

```
$species = 'spectest';
$family = 0;
$zones = 'zonestest';
$marker = 0;

echo create_query($species, $family, $zones, $marker);
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_ plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '%spectest%' AND Zones LIKE '%zonestest%';
```

### **Example #2:**

```
$species = 0;
$family = 0;
$zones = 0;
$marker = 0;

var_dump(create_query($species, $family, $zones, $marker));
```

**Output:**

```
bool(false)
```

Or, if you want to return query string without conditions instead of **false**, just replace **return** line in the function with:

```
return $noopt ? "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_ plants;" : "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_ plants WHERE $cond;";
```

---

Now if you want to do this in your way with a lot of IF, ELSEIF and ELSE statements, there's solution:

### Solution without function

(it works the same way like function above):

```
  if ($species == 0 && $family == 0 && $zones == 0 && $marker == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants";
    }
  elseif ($species == 0 && $family == 0 && $zones == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Marker LIKE '$marker%'";
    }
  elseif ($species == 0 && $family == 0 && $marker == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Zones LIKE '$zones%'";
    }
  elseif ($species == 0 && $zones == 0 && $marker == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Family LIKE '$family%'";
    }
  elseif ($family == 0 && $zones == 0 && $marker == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '$species%'";
    }
  elseif ($species == 0 && $family == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Zones LIKE '$zones%' AND Marker LIKE '$marker%'";
    }
  elseif ($species == 0 && $zones == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Family LIKE '$family%' AND Marker LIKE '$marker%'";
    }
  elseif ($species == 0 && $marker == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Family LIKE '$family%' AND Zones LIKE '$zones%'";
    }
  elseif ($family == 0 && $zones == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '$species%' AND Marker LIKE '$marker%'";
    }
  elseif ($family == 0 && $marker == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '$species%' AND Zones LIKE '$zones%'";
    }
  elseif ($zones == 0 && $marker == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '$species%' AND Family LIKE '$family%'";
    }
  elseif ($species == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Family LIKE '$family%' AND Zones LIKE '$zones%' AND Marker LIKE '$marker%'";
    }
  elseif ($family == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '$species%' AND Zones LIKE '$zones%' AND Marker LIKE '$marker%'";
    }
  elseif ($zones == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '$species%' AND Family LIKE '$family%' AND Marker LIKE '$marker%'";
    }
  elseif ($marker == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '$species%' AND Family LIKE '$family%' AND Zones LIKE '$zones%'";
    }
  else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants WHERE Speciesname LIKE '$species%' AND Family LIKE '$family%' AND Zones LIKE '$zones%' AND Marker LIKE '$marker%'";
    }

  // here you have your $sql ... now do whatever you want with your query
  echo $sql;
```

This code has been tested with every possible situation so if it still doesn't work, your problem is not in PHP example you posted above. I **don't recommend** this way because this is totally wrong approach, even for beginners.

If you still want to make it with IF/ELSE/ELSEIF consider condition(s) checking IF variable IS NOT EQUAL to zero. You'll get less code and easier implementation. Something like this:

### Different aproach

```
$species = 0;
$family = 0;
$zones = 0;
$marker = 0;

// default query w/out conditions
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ncbi_bold_plants";

// conditions array
$conditions = array();

// adding condition to array for every parameter <> 0
if ($species != 0) $conditions[] = "Speciesname LIKE '$species%'";
if ($family != 0) $conditions[] = "Family LIKE '$family%'";
if ($zones != 0) $conditions[] = "Zones LIKE '$zones%'";
if ($marker != 0) $conditions[] = "Marker LIKE '$marker%'";

// all we need now is to concatenate array elements with " AND " glue
$sql_cond = join(" AND ", $conditions);

// last thing, adding condition(s) to the main query (if there's any)
if ($sql_cond != '') $sql .= " WHERE $sql_cond";

// let see what we have now
echo $sql;
```

First 4 lines are for testing only. Now, we have same solution like previous ones but with less code (8 lines only).

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: thnx , but i'm still not able to get it through.. :( Is there any way that i can simply modify my IF statements? I've edited my code, kindly give me further guidance.

Comment: @Snids, you have to write your code over again because there are a lot of logical errors in this sample. First IF works in almost every condition and that's why it skips rest of the code. Your first (initial IF) checks if any of 4 statements is 0 and that's OK but look at following IF. `if(($species==0) && ($family==0) && ($zones==0))` gives you a resulting query if $species, $family and $zones are 0 and that doesn't check state of $marker variable. So it fires every time whatever you have as $marker's value. You made it so complicated and no one likes to read miles of code.

Comment: Also, if you want to make it with IF, ELSE, ELSEIF, you should start from largest possible condition (where all 4 vars are 0, than check combinations of 3, than check pairs and at the end check single values. That's only way to do it this way. Your method is totally wrong so I suggest using function to make your code as short as possible.

Comment: hey i appreciate your efforts a lot, but i dont know where's it going wrong.. I tried out with the function as well, but doesn't give the desired results. 
I checked with the IF coding, logically its absolutely correct, but while processing, it somehow skips the rest of the IF statements, and takes only the first one, (in the function too ) ..

Any help? please.!

Comment: your last approach I found the most accurate, but still it takes only the condition-less statement :(

Comment: hey thanks! i actually worked a lot on the if statements and replaced the value to 'all' from '0', voila, it all went working..! Maybe the problem was with the IF statement being used only for strings I suppose! anyways thnx a lot, got to learn variations..!

Comment: @Snids, the best way is testing. Always try to make simulation of expected results before you mark your code as correct. Always consider different methods and try to find the best and the quickest one. Also, in this specific case, filter your form values before you put them into query or you can lost your database by sql injection (or get it damaged). Not that hard, just make sure that all values your form passes into php script have expected results (do double check from php). Have a nice coding ;)

Comment: yes i get your point.. Thanks for the advice, I'll surely keep that in mind ..!

Answer (score 1):

Why not create dynamic dropdown menu from the fields? For eg. (I am using this on my own page, you'll have to edit the SQL syntax/query accordingly

```
echo "\n\t<select name='cat'>";
echo "\n\t\t<option value=''>Search all...</option>";
$connect = mysql_connect( <connection settings> );
$ctgTableCmd = "SELECT name FROM offliner.ctgtable ORDER BY name ASC";
$getCtg = mysql_query( $ctgTableCmd );
while( $ctgTable = mysql_fetch_array( $getCtg ) )
{
    $ctgVal = $ctgTable[0];
    echo "\n\t\t<option value=$ctgTable[0]>" . ucfirst( $ctgTable[0] ) . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: the issue is that i don want it for only only a single field, its for 4 field search at a time, namely: species, genus, zones and marker. Kindly be a bit elaborate, since i'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this code.first customize for yourself :

```
<?php
$where = '';
if(isset($_POST))
{
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
    {
        $q[] = $k.' LIKE \'%'.$v.'%\'';
    }
    $where = implode(' AND ',$q);
}
if(!empty($where))
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `ncbi_bold_ plants` WHERE '.$where;
else
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `ncbi_bold_ plants`"; 
    ......
    ......
```

Comment: ummm i'm a newbie, not really able to get what u'r trying to say. Will this code help in multiple search criteria?

Answer (score 0):

```
try using following approach

if($species)
{
  $colum='Species';
  $val=$family;
}
else
if($family)
{
  $colum='Family';
  $val=$family;
}
else
if($zones)
{
  $colum='Zones';
  $val=$zones;
}
else
if($marker)
{
  $colum='Marker';
  $val=$marker;
}
else
{
$column='';
$val='';

}

$sql="SELECT * FROM `ncbi_bold_ plants` WHERE $column LIKE '%".$val."%'" ;
```

Comment: the field "$colum='Zones';" and others gives a specific search for a particular Zones.. I've given a drop-down menu in other html page for the choice of specific field